# Create looper for sensors without callbacks?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-looper

I'm working on a project that wants to briefly sample Android sensors. Here, briefly is about 200 to 400 milliseconds (that's about the blink of an eye, literally).

I want to avoid Android's asynchronous-ness and use `ALooper_pollOnce` or `ALooper_pollAll`. Avoiding it simplifies programming and auditing because I can use a ladder diagram rather than a state machine to model the system. And the time is so brief that it should not be an issue in practice.

The following code:

```cxx
#include "android_native_app_glue.h"
...

// Should be defined in app_glue
#ifndef LOOPER_ID_USER
# define LOOPER_ID_USER 3
#endif
...

static const int LOOPER_ID_PRNG = LOOPER_ID_USER + 1;
...

ALooper* looper = ALooper_forThread();
if (looper == NULL)
    looper = ALooper_prepare(ALOOPER_PREPARE_ALLOW_NON_CALLBACKS);
...

ASensorEventQueue* queue = ASensorManager_createEventQueue(sensorManager,
    looper, LOOPER_ID_PRNG, NULL /*SensorEvent*/,
    reinterpret_cast<void*>(&context));
```

Causes the following error in logcat:

```
09-03 01:30:00.100: E/Looper(4026): Invalid attempt to set NULL callback but not 
                                    allowed for this looper.
```

How can I create a looper that allows polling? Or, if the looper exists, how do I modify it to allow polling?

---

```cxx
struct Sensor {
    Sensor() :
        m_type(-1), m_sensor(NULL) {
    }

    explicit Sensor(int type, string name, const ASensor* sensor) :
        m_type(type), m_name(name), m_sensor(sensor) {
    }

    int m_type;
    string m_name;
    const ASensor* m_sensor;
};

typedef vector<Sensor> SensorList;
```

And:

```cxx
static SensorList s_list;
// Double checked initialization omitted

ASensorList sensorList;
ASensorManager* sensorManager = ASensorManager_getInstance();

int n = ASensorManager_getSensorList(sensorManager, &sensorList);

if( n < 0)
{
    LOG_ERROR("SensorList: failed to retrieve list");
}
else if (n == 0)
{
    LOG_DEBUG("SensorList: no sensors available");
}
else
{
    s_list.reserve(static_cast<size_t>(n));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        const ASensor* sensor = sensorList[i];
        if (sensor == NULL)
            continue;

        const char* name = ASensor_getName(sensor);
        const char* vendor = ASensor_getVendor(sensor);
        int type = ASensor_getType(sensor);
        int min_delay = ASensor_getMinDelay(sensor);
        float resolution = ASensor_getResolution(sensor);

        LOG_DEBUG("SensorList: %s (%s) %d %d %f", name, vendor, type, min_delay, resolution);

        // These sensors require callbacks. Avoid them for simplicity.
        if (type == ASENSOR_TYPE_LIGHT || min_delay == 0)
            continue;

        s_list.push_back(Sensor(type, name, sensor));
    }
}
```

---

Below, the light sensor requires a callback because its `min_delay` is 0. It was not added to the `SensorList`. The other sensors were added to the `SensorList`.

The output was created by this line:

```cxx
LOG_DEBUG("SensorList: %s (%s) %d %d %f", name, vendor, type, min_delay, resolution);
```

```
D/PRNG ( 3950): SensorList: MPL rotation vector (Invensense) 11 20000 1.000000
D/PRNG ( 3950): SensorList: MPL linear accel (Invensense) 10 20000 1.000000
D/PRNG ( 3950): SensorList: MPL gravity (Invensense) 9 20000 1.000000
D/PRNG ( 3950): SensorList: MPL Gyro (Invensense) 4 20000 1.000000
D/PRNG ( 3950): SensorList: MPL accel (Invensense) 1 20000 1.000000
D/PRNG ( 3950): SensorList: MPL magnetic field (Invensense) 2 20000 1.000000
D/PRNG ( 3950): SensorList: MPL Orientation (Invensense) 3 20000 1.000000
D/PRNG ( 3950): SensorList: Lite-On al3000a Ambient Light Sensor (Lite-On) 5 0 1.000000
D/PRNG ( 3950): SensorList: added 7 sensors
```

Comment: In truth, the ability to avoid ALooper altogether might be even more pleasant.

Answer (score 1):

This part

```
ALooper* looper = ALooper_forThread();
if (looper == NULL)
    looper = ALooper_prepare(ALOOPER_PREPARE_ALLOW_NON_CALLBACKS);
```

can be simplified to

```
ALooper* looper = ALooper_prepare(ALOOPER_PREPARE_ALLOW_NON_CALLBACKS);
```

as `ALooper_prepare` returns the looper associated with the thread, if it exists, according to the doc in `looper.h` This might even solves your problem b/c it might change the looper so it allows non-callbacks, but I'm not sure.

Although be aware that you should fully control the looper yourself, i.e. if a looper is already polled somewhere else, I think you cannot poll the same looper yourself without interfering. So either you modify the looper in `android_native_app_glue` or your write a new looper, in a **new thread**. This is my understanding.